# Не выполняются аспекты aspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

Не выполняются аспекты, хотя срез указан верно, буду рад любой подсказке

[image: Класс с аспектами]

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Так а разве там аннотацию среза не нужно сначала указывать?@PointCut

Comment: Cкорее всего вам надо настроить мавен плагин.

Comment: @PointCut не нужна,

Answer (score 3):

с POM файлом, ниже всё заработало. Для того чтобы работало под томкатом, ещё пришлось в папку lib в каталоге томката, добавить жарку для aspectJ

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <!-- new configuration is here -->
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```